# Group By - How to retrieve an associated field?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, greatest-n-per-group

Expected result of the here below SELECT statement:

```
('2015-01-15',110,'John')
```

Here below some code to help me out...

```
 DECLARE @MyTableVar table(
arrival_date date,
nb_sales int,
name varchar(255)
)

insert into @MyTableVar values
('2015-01-15',121,'James'),
('2015-01-15',110,'John')

select 
arrival_date,
MIN(nb_sales) as nb_sales,
name <<-- What should I put knowing I can't put MIN or MAX ?
from @MyTableVar
group by arrival_date
```

Comment: What do you want to happen if multiple rows have the same (minimum) number of sales on the same day?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use windowed function:

```
;WITH cte AS
(
  SELECT *, r = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY arrival_date ORDER BY nb_sales)
  FROM @MyTableVar
)
SELECT arrival_date, nb_sales, name
FROM cte
WHERE r = 1;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/417322)**</kbd>

If ties are possible and you want both of them use `RANK()` instead of `ROW_NUMBER()`

Answer (score 0):

You could join the group to the original data set and get the name from the result set created from the join:

```
select x2.*
    from (
    select 
      arrival_date,
      MIN(nb_sales) nb_sales
    from @MyTableVar
    group by arrival_date) x1
    inner join @MyTableVar x2 on 
      x1.arrival_date = x2.arrival_date and 
      x1.nb_sales = x2.nb_sales
```